# What frequency are data generated through arima.sim() function in R?

Tags: r, time-series, arima

Often times, time series data are generated through `arima.sin()` function in `R`, I want to know what frequency such time series data is coming out with? Can it be daily, weekly, monthly or yearly frequency so I can know how to handle its analysis. For instance, if I need to turn it to it to time series data in `R`, I write:

```
data1 <- arima.sim(n, model = list(ar=phi, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
data <- ts(data1, frequency =12)# or frequency = 7, 4, 1 etc
```

Especially if I have to do time series decomposition that I have to write this in `R`:

```
#time series decomposition
DECOMPOSE<-decompose(data1,type=c("additive","multiplicative"),filter = NULL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arima.sim` from the base R doesn't allow seasonal ARIMA models.

I suggest forecast R package which has a function 'simulate`for this. Also there seems to be a package`sarima` with a sim_arima function that might suit your purpose.